# jquery append nested elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, append

I need to append nested element to the page

I am using the append function, but running into an error trying to pass an array to it.

```
<div id="area">
</div>

var data = [{"class":"a", "href":"http://google.com"}, {"class":"b", "href":"http://yahoo.com"}];

$('#area').append(
    $('<ul>').append(
        $(data).each(function(i, val) {
            $('<li>', {class: val["class"]}).append(
                $('<a>', {href: val["href"]})
        })
    )
)
```

When I do this I get an error on the input of the append function because I am passing .each.  I need to do this dynamically based on a given array to add a set of nested elements so in the end it would be.

```
<div id="area">
    <ul>
        <li class="b">
            <a href="http://yahoo.com"></a>
        </li>
        <li class="a">
            <a href="http://google.com"></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

So I am wondering how to pass .each to append, or do something similar in a different way.

Thanks to all in advanced!

Comment: your mark up is invalid child of `UL` should be an `LI` then you have have the span with anchor in it

Comment: haha i just saw that thanks, fixed it! That's not the issue here

Comment: `append` takes an array of DOM elements not a a plain object. You need to iterate over the array and append the items inside that loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var data = [{
  "class": "a",
  "href": "http://google.com"
}, {
  "class": "b",
  "href": "http://yahoo.com"
}];
var ul = $('<ul/>'); //create the ul
$(data).each(function(i, val) { //loop the data
  ul.append('<li class=' + val.class + '><a href=' + val.href + '>' + val.href + '</li>'); //append each value on li the class and href
  $('#area').append(ul) //append the ul to the div
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="area">
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, very helpful!!

Comment: @user1807880 glad to help mate happy coding :)

Answer (score 1):

Nothing in your code is appending the `<li>`s to `<ul>` because `$(data).each` returns the `data` array wrapped in jQuery object.

You should use [`$.each`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) to iterate over non-jQuery objects, and always try to cache references and do manipulations in memory before attaching to DOM.

Note that unlike the other answer, below code manipulates the actual DOM only once.

```js
var data = [{
  "class": "a",
  "href": "http://google.com"
}, {
  "class": "b",
  "href": "http://yahoo.com"
}];
var $ul = $('<ul>');
$.each(data, function(i, val) {
  var $li = $('<li>', {
    class: val["class"]
  });
  $li.append(
    $('<a>', {
      href: val["href"],
      text: val["href"]
    }));
  $ul.append($li);
});
$('#area').append($ul);
//--------^--- one time DOM manipulation
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="area">

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, very helpful!!

Got one little q.  Say I want to make the href a xlink:href, custom attribute.  How do I do so.  Defining it like
        $('<a>', { xlink:href: 'http://google.com' });

Comment: @user1807880 simply changing `href` to `"xlink:href"`  (with quotes) seems to work fine?